# merge rows into new column value

Tags: python, pandas

I am taking a df that is all dup value pairs and then from the 2nd row take the 2nd column value and add it to the first row in a new column called 'new_amt' then inserting NaN for the second row and new third column. After I'll drop all row that contain NaN.

so the dataframe look like this:

|  | ref_num | Amt | fy | fund_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row 1 | 1 | 10 | 21 | IX |
| row 2 | 1 | 20 | 21 | IX |
| row 3 | 2 | 5 | 22 | III |
| row 4 | 2 | 15 | 22 | III |
| row 5 | 3 | 12 | 20 | VI |
| row 6 | 3 | 7 | 20 | VI |

after it should look like this:

|  | ref_num | Amt | new_Amt | fy | fund_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row 1 | 1 | 10 | 20 | 21 | IX |
| row 2 | 1 | 20 | NaN | 21 | IX |
| row 3 | 2 | 5 | 15 | 22 | III |
| row 4 | 2 | 15 | NaN | 22 | III |
| row 5 | 3 | 12 | 7 | 20 | VI |
| row 6 | 3 | 7 | NaN | 20 | VI |

I thought a lambda function could work where I'd have the else statement return NaN for all the second dup rows but I could figure out the syntax.

> 

df['new_Amt'] = df.apply(lambda x : x['Amt'] if x['ref_num'] == x['ref_num'] else x['new_Amt'] is NaN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do both operations at once (resolve duplicates as you describe and drop the redundant rows)?

```py
k = 'ref_num'
newdf = df.drop_duplicates(subset=k, keep='first').merge(
    df.drop_duplicates(subset=k, keep='last'), on='ref_num', suffixes=('', '_new'))
>>> newdf
   ref_num  Amt  Amt_new
0        1   10       20
1        2    5       15
2        3   12        7
```

Another possibility:

```py
gb = df.groupby('ref_num')['Amt']
newdf = pd.concat([gb.first(), gb.last()], axis=1, keys=['Amt', 'new_Amt']).reset_index()
>>> newdf
   ref_num  Amt  new_Amt
0        1   10       20
1        2    5       15
2        3   12        7
```

Note: in your question it is not clear if `'row 1'`, `'row 2'` etc. are indices, meant to be kept or not, etc. If they are desired in the final output, please let us know if and how they should appear.

**Addendum**: what if `df` has more columns?

Here is a way to keep the whole "first" rows, and only add the column `new_Amt`:

```py
gb = df.groupby('ref_num')
newdf = pd.concat([gb.first(), gb['Amt'].last().to_frame('new_Amt')], axis=1).reset_index()
```

Example:

```py
df = df.rename_axis(index='foo').reset_index()

# code above

>>> newdf
   ref_num    foo  Amt  new_Amt
0        1  row 1   10       20
1        2  row 3    5       15
2        3  row 5   12        7
```

Comment: both solutions worked when i tested them out. The only thing I noticed is that in the first if I have more columns they get duplicated with the '_new' suffix, and in the second example any additional columns seem to be cut entirely. I know that wasn't shown in example I gave. Row numbers weren't relevant to me.

Comment: See addendum above.